# Javascript: regex polyfill to 'y' flag in IE

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer

I'm writing a dynamic regex to use it in an autocomplete control, but I neeed to support Internet Explorer. The problem, 'y' flag is not supported(IE). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/sticky

My example regex:

```
/Some text/giy.test('Some')
```

Output:

```
Syntax error in regular expression
```

Any one know a polyfill?

Comment: If MDN doesn't have a polyfill, chances are, it's not possible to polyfill the behaviour (just as you can't polyfill arrow functions, const, generators, etc)

Comment: Yes, you're right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't a oficial regex but is a way to validate the same:

```
var reg = 'Some Text';
var search = 'Some';
var isSticky = reg.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLocaleLowerCase()) === 0;
```

The code could be wrap in a function to make the polyfill